# Installing php phalcon extension

Tags: software-installation, php, gcc

I am unable to install phalcon php extension by folowing these steps.

I use 64-bit Linux Mint 14 Nadia.

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html#linux-solaris-mac

For the Prerequisite packages I use:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/installing-php5-and-apache-on-ubuntu/
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers

Git is working fine.

I really follow steps straight forward, once I am finish I edit /etc/php5/cli/php.ini ny adding `extension=phalcon.so` just before module settings section.

Then i restart apache with command `sudo service apache2 restart`

After installing phalcon [dev tools](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tools.html) and running command

```
phalcon create-project proj_name
```

it reports

> phalcon: command not found

I have tried the same steps with installing xammp, I did not have luck also.

Am I doing something wrong in the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devtools installation script is a bit buggy. You can install it fairly easy by just cloning the code from git and to create symlink to the phalcon.php.

1. go to some folder (let say it's user's home folder) and clone the devtools with:

   cd ~
   git clone https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git
2. create symlink and change it's permissions:

   ln -s ~/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon
   chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/phalcon

And that should be it. When you run phalcon in terminal it should give you the list of commands. If it complains about phalcon not installed, then you have to add line

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

to php.ini of your cli since you probably changed just apache's php.ini or whatever server you are using.